# Finding the value of some coefficients such that an equation is true

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, coefficients

I have some expression that is a function of some variables $q_i$ and some coefficients $\gamma_j$, which is equal to zero,

$$ f(q_i, \gamma_i) = 0$$

I want to find the value of the coefficients, such that this is true. It is trivially satisfied for all $\gamma_i = 0$. I want any non-trivial solutions.

For a simpler equation, this could be done by hand by e.g. comparing powers of $q_i$. Is there a way to do this in mathematica?

Comment: This is too broad. Recommend that you include a specific example demonstrating your problem and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html).

> `SolveAlways[eqns,vars]`
>   gives the values of parameters that make the equations `eqns` valid for all values of the variables `vars`.

Comment: This looks useful! Is there a way to distinguish between variables, parameters and constants?

Comment: I don't know; I suggest you read its documentation page in full.  It's not long.